# WCF Data Service Many-to-Many Relationship with EF4

Tags: linq, wcf, entity-framework, many-to-many, wcf-data-services

I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC 2 application that uses Entity Framework 4 and WCF Data Services.

I want to manipulate the many-to-many (composite key) relationship between Duties and Workers based on the state of some checkboxes.

A Worker may have zero or more duties. A Duty may have zero or more workers.

This code is from one of my controllers:

```
//
// POST: /Duty/Edit/5

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Duty Model, FormCollection collection)
{
    ctx.AttachTo("Duties", Model);
    ctx.UpdateObject(Model);

    // handle checkboxes
    ctx.LoadProperty(Model, "Workers");
    foreach (Worker w in ctx.Workers)
    {
        bool isChecked = collection[w.Id.ToString()].Contains("t");
        bool wasChecked = Model.Workers.Contains(w);
        if (isChecked && !wasChecked)
        {
            Model.Workers.Add(w);
        }
        else if (wasChecked && !isChecked)
        {
            Model.Workers.Remove(w);
        }
    }

    ctx.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The `Add()` and `Remove()` methods are called appropriately. This executes without exception. But, the changes don't get committed to my database. Why?

### Update

I've tried flipping it around to `w.Duties.Add(Model);` and that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use methods [AddLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.addlink.aspx) and [DeleteLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.deletelink.aspx).

```
//
// POST: /Duty/Edit/5

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Duty Model, FormCollection collection)
{
    ctx.AttachTo("Duties", Model);
    ctx.UpdateObject(Model);

    // handle checkboxes
    foreach (Worker w in ctx.Workers.Expand("Duties"))
    {
        bool isChecked = collection[w.Id.ToString()].Contains("t");
        bool wasChecked = w.Duties.Contains(Model);
        if (isChecked && !wasChecked)
        {
            ctx.AddLink(Model, "Workers", w);
        }
        else if (wasChecked && !isChecked)
        {
            ctx.DeleteLink(Model, "Workers", w);
        }
    }

    ctx.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

See the *Creating and Modifying Relationship Links* section of MSDN article [Updating the Data Service (WCF Data Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756361.aspx)